# Firefox bug - video does not mute when it is cloned with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, html5-video

Firefox does not mute the video when the video element is cloned with jQuery.

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var origin = $('.item-video');
    var target = $('.clone');

    origin.clone(true).appendTo(target);
    origin.empty();fix

});
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="item-video">
    <video width="560" height="315" autoplay muted controls loop>
        <source src="big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
        <!-- <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm"> -->
    </video>
    <a href="yourpage.html" class="button-video"></a>
</div>

<div class="clone">

</div><div class="item-video">
    <video width="560" height="315" autoplay muted controls loop>
        <source src="big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
        <!-- <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm"> -->
    </video>
    <a href="yourpage.html" class="button-video"></a>
</div>

<div class="clone">

</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0map4c8/)

Any ideas how I can **fix** the bug on Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this is happening on FF but this is the workaround

```
origin.clone(true).appendTo(target).find('video').attr('onloadedmetadata','this.muted =true');
```